# Django admin site models editing not working with gunicorn wsgi

Tags: django-models, django-admin, wsgi, gunicorn, django-wsgi

On running with DEBUG=False

```
gunicorn pursuite.wsgi:application
```

Models in admin site are just text not even a link, I would say i can't even read models in admin site. But every thing works fine when DEBUG=True or run from **manage.py runserver**

All settings are same. Project dir tree is as following:

```
.
|-- apps
|   |-- admin
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- models
|   |   |   |-- company.py
|   |   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- tests
|   |   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |   |-- test_company.py
|   |   `-- views
|   |       |-- __init__.py
|   |       `-- site.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- libs
|-- LICENSE
|-- manage.py
|-- pursuite
|   |-- doc
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings
|   |   |-- common.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- local_settings.py
|   |   |-- production.py
|   |   |-- staging.py
|   |   `-- testing.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- web
|   |   |-- static
|   |   `-- templates
|   `-- wsgi.py
|-- README.md
|-- setup.cfg
`-- setup.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just now.

Adding

```
admin.autodiscover()
```

to **urls.py** worked for me.